# Getting the key on Java Endpoint

Tags: java, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

I need to do some additional validations on server side (Java Endpoint) for each upload performed directly to the AWS S3.

Due to that I need to get the Key and the File Name on each request that Fine Uploader (Javascript code) sends to my Java endpoint.

I'm trying to use `String key = req.getParameter("key");` but due to the asynchronous call, I'm getting several null values.

How can I get the Key at the beginning of each request that I'm receiving on my Java Endpoint?

Tks in advance.

My Java Endpoint follows the default endpoint of the [documentation](https://github.com/FineUploader/server-examples/blob/master/java/s3/S3Uploads.java).

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
            if (req.getParameter("status").equals("signature"))
                handleSignatureRequest(req, resp);
            else if (req.getParameter("status").equals("success"))
                handleUploadSuccessRequest(req, resp);
        }
```

And my script:

```
 <script>
    var uploader = new qq.s3.FineUploader({
    element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-s3"), 
    debug: true,
    template: 'qq-template-s3',
         request: {
             endpoint: "myendpoint.s3.amazonaws.com",
             accessKey: "my_key"
            },
            signature: {
                endpoint: "http://example.org?status=signature"
            },
            uploadSuccess: {
                endpoint: "http://example.org?status=success",
                params: {
                    isBrowserPreviewCapable:         qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews
                }
            },
            objectProperties: {
            key: function (fileId) {
                return '2016/04/13/2502198001/' + this.getName(fileId);
                  }
            },
            retry: {
                enableAuto: true
             },
            iframeSupport: {
                localBlankPagePath: "/server/success.html"
            },
            cors: {
                expected: false
            },
            chunking: {
                enabled: true
            },
            resume: {
                enabled: true
            },
            deleteFile: {
                enabled: false,
                method: "POST",
                endpoint: "http://example.org"
            },
            validation: {
                itemLimit: 5,
                sizeLimit: 15000000
            },
            thumbnails: {
                placeholders: {
                    notAvailablePath: "/uploader/placeholders/not_available-generic.png",
                    waitingPath: "/uploader/placeholders/waiting-generic.png"
                }
            },
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You are going to have to post some more code for people to be able to help you.

Comment: Done - tks Robert.

Comment: You are doing things exactly correctly. There is nothing async on the server side. I will point out that the only POST request I see has no status parameter.

Comment: Yes, even if I add POST method on signature method, I'm still not able to get the key value all the times. I think that could be something related with the upload time. Any ideas?

Comment: "Im still not able to get the key value all the times." You mean it works sometimes?  Test the endpoint in a tool like postman (or other tool) to see where the problem lies.

Comment: I already did that. For some reason I just got the key value only when status is success - when is signature is always null. 

In other words, the key value is not available on the server endpoint at the beginning of the request - just at the end when the upload is done.

Comment: You should be able to get the key out of the policy or headers to sign, but why do you need this?

Comment: Hi Ray, I'm supposed to change the directory dynamically on my bucket depending of file extension, also validate the request depending of internal id's of our application and user logged.

I've tried to add the parameter using params option, but I still not able to get the key value.

Could you explain how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable S3 Events, then a file create event could trigger an AWS Lamba written in Python, Java or javascript, and you could do the extra processing whenever a file is completed being created. The first 1 million Lamba executions per month are free.